# Postfix evaluation of an expression

Tags: python-3.x, postfix-mta

There is some issue with this code, as it is not returning negative results, only the positive part is getting returned.

I am not getting why it is not appending the last value along with its sign(if any) as per the input.

```
from collections import deque

ex = '231*+9-'
q = deque()

for i in ex:
    if i.isdigit():
        q.append(i)
    else:
        a= q.pop()
        b= q.pop()
        q.append(str(eval(a + i + b)))
print(q)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporarily modify your code thus for debugging:

```
from collections import deque

ex = '231*+9-'
q = deque()

for i in ex:
    if i.isdigit():
        q.append(i)
    else:
        a = q.pop()
        b = q.pop()
        q.append(str(eval(a + i + b)))
    print('debug:', i, q)               # Just add this line.
print(q)
```

You will then be able to see more clearly what is happening:

```
debug: 2 deque(['2'])
debug: 3 deque(['2', '3'])
debug: 1 deque(['2', '3', '1'])
debug: * deque(['2', '3'])
debug: + deque(['5'])
debug: 9 deque(['5', '9'])
debug: - deque(['4'])
deque(['4'])
```

Hence you can see that it appears to be mostly working. If you expected it to subtract `9` from `5` in that final step (and this seems likely based on use of RPN), then you have the variables in the wrong order. They should be:

```
b = q.pop() # Swap these
a = q.pop() #   two around.
q.append(str(eval(a + i + b)))
```

As it is, you're putting `9` into `a` and `5` into `b`, then evaluating `a - b`, or `9 - 5`. Fixing it as per the suggestion gives you:

```
debug: 2 deque(['2'])
debug: 3 deque(['2', '3'])
debug: 1 deque(['2', '3', '1'])
debug: * deque(['2', '3'])
debug: + deque(['5'])
debug: 9 deque(['5', '9'])
debug: - deque(['-4'])
deque(['-4'])
```